# What's the difference between venv and External Libraries?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

New programmer here. I am using the PyCharm IDE and I noticed that Python 3.6 is listed in both "venv" as well as "External Libraries".

I looked into the folders and noticed they contain a lot of different packages, for example `django` is only in my venv, and `urllib` is only in my external library. But then some packages are in both, like `pip`.

There's also a site-packages folder in External Library that appears the same as the one in my venv. It even has the same dark yellow text coloring.

My understanding is the venv is a virtual environment separate from my main system environment, and then according to [this link](https://hadihariri.com/2014/01/06/intellij-idea-minimal-survival-guide/#external-libraries) the External Libraries are libraries "not internal to my project." By these definitions of venv and External library, they don't seem mutually exclusive (i.e. opposites of each other) so, I'm just not sure what I'm looking at.

What's contained in the venv vs the External Library? 
Can the exact same file (i.e. same system file path) show up in both locations?

[image: What I'm looking at]

Answer (score 1):

> I looked into the folders and noticed they contain a lot of different packages

Where exactly did you look? Are you sure this venv is selected as a project interpreter in **Settings | Project Interpreter**?

External libraries do contain your venv site-packages, but they also contain the standard library from the base interpreter used to create the venv, typeshed stubs, binary skeletons generated by PyCharm and other things from interpreter paths:

[image]

Please also note - a venv may be stored outside of PyCharm.

Comment: Yeah, my venv is located in my Interpreter Paths, like in your picture. Also, it looks like my venv contains a file called "python" located at the path "/home/MyUser/PycharmProjects/MyPyCharmProject/venv/bin/python" that matches the directory of my Python3.6 external library. Does this make sense? Maybe I'm just not understanding why it seems like "venv" is located both at venv and External Libraries. Like are they different or the same file? And if they're the same file, what's the philosophy for having it in both places?

Comment: I've been thinking about the project structure as if it were a system file folder structure. So it's a bit unintuitive to me if they share files, shown in kind of arbitrary locations in the tree.